# convolutional VAE can not run, and I can't find anything wrong

Tags: keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, autoencoder, kaggle

here is my cvae model:

```
def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    eps = tf.random.normal(tf.shape(z_log_var), dtype=tf.float32, mean=0., stddev=1.0, name='epsilon')
    z = z_mean + tf.exp(z_log_var / 2) * eps
    return z

# parameters
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)# MNIST
batch_size = 128
filters = 32
latent_dim = 2
epochs = 30

# encoder
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape, name='input')
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters*2, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
# shape info needed to build decoder model
shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
# generate latent vector Q(z|X)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
z_mean = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x)
z = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(sampling, name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
encoder.summary()

# decoder
latent_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3], activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters*2, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(x)
decoder = tf.keras.Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()

# convolutional VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
cvae = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name='cvae')

# reconstruction loss
reconstruction_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(inputs, outputs)
# reconstruction_loss = reconstruction_loss * num_features# num_features=784. this is a cvae, not vae, so I commented this line.
# KL Divergence loss
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
kl_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
cvae_loss = tf.reduce_mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
cvae.add_loss(cvae_loss)
cvae.compile(optimizer='adam')
cvae.summary()

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train, X_test = X_train / 255., X_test / 255.
X_train, X_test = X_train.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]), X_test.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32, copy=False)
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32, copy=False)

cvae.fit(X_train, None, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_test, None))# occur something wrong
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytcqx.png)

The error message said "Incompatible shapes", however I not know where to modify thus they can be compatible.

I learned this convolutional variantional autoencoder model from kaggle, the source reference link is right [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/fazilbtopal/variantional-autoencoders-vae), please focus on the cVAE part not others.

I followed the kaggle writer's code step by step, it seems that this code works well in kaggle, but fails to run in jupyter notebook, but I really wanna use jupyter notebook. can you gays solve it?